# Having trouble with JFile Chooser and Buffered Reader

Tags: java, file-io, stack, jfilechooser

I am trying to create a program that will evaluate expressions using a stack for a project for a class. I am not done with it yet, I am just getting things to go onto one of two stacks, an operators stack and an operands stack. Everything was working that way I intended until I created a method that would check the priority of the operators stack, how it works is plus and minus signs have lowest priority then it goes multiplication and division signs and greater than or equal signs have highest priority. This method in my code is called checkPred and when this method is commented out my JFile Chooser works and reads in the data from the file but when its not commented out my JFile Chooser does not work and in my try/catch statement it executes the catch block which results in an output of Error!. The .txt file I am reading from contains this: 4*6*5-9

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
public class Evaluate 
{
  static Stack<Character> operators = new Stack<Character>();
  static Stack<Character> operands = new Stack<Character>();
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    int status;
    status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        try
        {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;
            while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
            {
                getCharAt(line);
            }
            buff.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Open File dialog canceled");
    }
  }
  public static void getCharAt(String x)
  {
    int charToInt;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        charToInt = x.charAt(i);
        if(charToInt >= 48 && charToInt != 60 && charToInt != 62 )
        {
            operands.push(x.charAt(i));
        }
        else 
        {
            if(checkPred(x.charAt(i),operators.peek()))
            {
                operators.push(x.charAt(i));
            }
        }           
    }
    System.out.println(operands);
    System.out.println(operators);      
  } 
  public static boolean checkPred(char op1, char op2)
  {
    int plusMinus = 1; 
    int multDivide = 2;
    int greaterLess = 3;
    int op1Value = 0;
    int op2Value = 0;       
    if(op1 == 43 || op1 == 45)
    {
        op1Value = plusMinus;
    }
    else if(op1 == 42 || op1 == 47)
    {
        op1Value = multDivide;
    }
    else if(op1 == 60 || op1 == 62)
    {
        op1Value = greaterLess;
    }


    if(op2 == 43 || op2 == 45)
    {
        op2Value = plusMinus;
    }
    else if(op2 == 42 || op2 == 47)
    {
        op1Value = multDivide;
    }
    else if(op2 == 60 || op2 == 62)
    {
        op2Value = greaterLess;
    }

    if(op1Value > op2Value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;       
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code:

```
if(checkPred(x.charAt(i),operators.peek()))
{
    operators.push(x.charAt(i));
}
```

On your first operator(the first '*') `operators.peek()` is called in the condition before `operators.push()` is called a single time.
This results in a `EmptyStackException` which is caught by the catch block in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the section which is you are adding `operators`  with this code. Otherwise the first time you are calling `checkPred` method  you got nothing  in the `operators` Stack to peek.

```
            if (operators.empty()) {
                operators.push(x.charAt(i));
            } else if (checkPred(x.charAt(i), operators.peek())) {
                operators.push(x.charAt(i));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the JFile Chooser or with the Buffered Reader. What causes the problem is that before you call operators.push(), you will need to populate the operands stack, otherwise it's going to throw an exception.

I am not sure how you are going to finish this calculator program, but if you need need to check the precedence the first time, you could do this:

- Add an element to the operators stack first, any character that you will not use later as an operator, like:

  `operators.push('@'); // @ = 64 in ascii`
- Complement your checkPred(char,char) method in a way that comparing 'any operator' and @ will always yield that the 'any operator' has a higher precedence. You could start your method like this:

  ```
  public static boolean checkPred(char op1, char op2){
  if (op1 == 64) return false;
  if (op2 == 64) return true;
  ```

One last thing, I am not an ASCII master, I needed to look up the values for each character you are using. If you convert the characters into ints and then put them inside if statements (or use comments like // 43 = '+'), it makes your code more readable and it will be much clearer for you as well when you look at this program again in a few weeks, months time.